# Wordpress PHP Google Sheets API Access

Tags: php, wordpress, google-sheets, google-authentication

I'm having issues accessing Google Sheets through PHP in WordPress (WP). I've accessed the same sheet before in a local python program and I recall that once the code first ran the google authorization window popped up asking for approval. This WP shortcode isn't getting to that point and instead outputs an error message to the WP page stating a valid API Key is missing. What am I missing here?

Shortcode:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    function excel_tester_function() {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('Google Sheets and PHP');
        $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/credentials.json');
        $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);
        $client->setAccessType('online');
        $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
        $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
        $spreadsheetId = '{SHEET_ID}';
        $get_range = '{RANGE}';
        $response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $get_range);
        $values = $response->getValues();
        foreach ($val as $values) {
            print($val);
        }
    }
    add_shortcode('excel-tester', 'excel_tester_function');
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.", "errors": [ { "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.", "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden" } ], "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } } in...
```

Please advise. Let me know if there is any info I can provide that could help solve this. Thank you.

Comment: If you're trying to write to a sheet using PHP ('server to server'), then you're best off using a service account. From reading your question, your previous implementation seems to have been user-initiated, which does not apply here.

Comment: @RoAchterberg ah yes, that's what I was going to try next. Attempted the API Key method first and failed. After a bit of googling, trial and error I got the Service Account method to work. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction.